# How to extend Salesforce setup screens

Tags: lightning, setup

How is it possible to extends Salesforce setup screens like below?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No. Setup screens are not customizable. It is conceptually possible to build a custom Setup app, but that would not be the same thing. I can't seem to find an Idea for this specifically, but it would probably be hard to find given the combination of words you'd have to use to even have a chance of finding the appropriate Idea.

Answer (score 1):

The app provider has a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elementscloud-catalyst/pdfdjfoigmkblodhcoclpnicpkplbjhf) which supplements the Salesforce setup screens.

> This Chrome Extension allows the ... documentation and analytics to be displayed inside Salesforce Setup in the right sidebar.