# Setup: add more tabs LEX

Tags: lightning-experience, setup

So by now we're all familiar with how LEX looks. Here's a snapshot of the Setup page.

[image: Wasted space and not enough tabs]

We get 2 tabs: Setup and Object Manager. Switching between them loses your place. Say I was inside an object and editing a formula field. Then I wanted to make a quick change to a Custom Label. So I switch to the other tab, find the label, make the change, then switch back to Object Manager. Boom, my progress is gone. I need to scroll and click and scroll and click to get back. And scrolling is expensive because of lazy loading the data.

But look! There's a ton of empty space to the right of those tabs! Surely I could open more tabs? Keep one open in this object, another in a different object, editing my labels in a third tab and managing a profile in a fourth?
Surely?

Comment: You might find this interesting [How to extend Salesforce setup screens](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258861/how-to-extend-salesforce-setup-screens), they did it by writing a custom [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, this would be useful.

But it is not possible at the moment.

Feel free to create a [Salesforce Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)

Comment: Have you seen something in the docs that this really isn't possible? Maybe we're not trying the right things...

Comment: @AvailableName Agree with Robs - definitely not possible and worth submitting as an idea.  You basically want Lightning Console functionality on the setup page :-)

Comment: @AvailableName Definitely not available. It'd be incredibly useful.